# iOS Keychain Wrapper Locksmith:- LocksmithError error 3

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am using `Locksmith` as my keychain wrapper for Swift, But it shows the following error when try to *save data*

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Locksmith.LocksmithError error 3.)
```

Here is the code that I am trying to save data to keychain

```
let datapair = ["Content": "value"]
do {
    try Locksmith.saveData(data: datapair, forUserAccount: "key")
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Any solutions or suggestions should be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error 3 occurs when the Keychain entry already exists. For the second time when you update the data, use

```
try Locksmith.updateData(data: datapair, forUserAccount: "key")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, `error` is provided to the `catch` block by default, so you don't need to explicitly write `catch let error`.

Comment: One more doubt is there any easy way to check, the key already exists or not?

Comment: You can simply directly use this method  and not use `saveData`